# ls | grep in shell written in C

Tags: c, shell

I am trying to make my own shell in C.  It uses one pipe and the input (for now) is static. I execute commands using execvp.
Everything is fine except when I run the command `ls |grep ".c"` I get no results. Can anyone show me where is the problem and find a solution.

The shell so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int   p[2];
int pid;
int r;

main()
{
    char *ls[] = {"ls", NULL};
    char *grep[] = {"grep", "\".c\"", NULL};

    pipe(p);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid  != 0) {
            // Parent: Output is to child via pipe[1]

            // Change stdout to pipe[1]
            dup2(p[1], 1);
            close(p[0]);

            r = execvp("ls", ls);
    } else {
            // Child: Input is from pipe[0] and output is via stdout.
            dup2(p[0], 0);
            close(p[1]);

            r = execvp("grep", grep);
            close(p[0]);
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Note that the C Shell ([tag:csh]) is quite different from a shell written in C (or, perhaps more accurately, it is a specific example of a shell written in C with a long heritage, having been written in the late 1970s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes in the argument to grep. i.e., use

```
char *grep[] = {"grep", ".c", NULL};
```

If you are calling `execvp`, the usual shell expansion of arguments (i.e., globbing, removal of quotes, etc) does not happen, so effectively what you are doing is the same as

```
ls | grep '".c"'
```

In a normal shell.

Also be aware that nothing that comes after the call to `execvp` will execute, `execvp` **replaces** the current process, it will never return.

Comment: Always place code after `execvp()` to detect and report failure to execute the command.  In a shell with a loop, if you don't take care about that, you can easily end up with multiple processes all trying to read from the terminal at once, which leads to chaos and confusion.

Comment: **And** be careful about what code that will be executed after a call to one of the `exec*()` functions fails after a call to `fork()` - among other things the `fork()` will duplicate all open file descriptors and streams **along with any data in buffers waiting to be written**.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems:

1. One problem is that you have far too few calls to `close()`.  When you use `dup2()` to replicate a file descriptor from a pipe to standard input or standard output, you should close *both* file descriptors returned by `pipe()`.
2. A second problem is that the shell removes double quotes around arguments but you've added them around your.  You are looking for files whose name contains `".c"` (where the double quotes are part of the file name being searched for).  Use:

   ```
   char *grep[] = { "grep", "\\.c$", NULL };
   ```

   This looks for a dot and a `c` at the end of the line.
3. You should report failures after `execvp()`.  If any of the `exec*()` functions returns, it failed.  It can happen when the user mistypes a command name, for example.  It is crucial that you report the error and that the child process then exits.  If you don't do that, you can end up in a normal iterative shell (rather than this one-shot, non-iterative, non-interactive shell) with multiple shell processes all trying to read from the terminal at the same time, which leads to chaos and confusion.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: Oh, of course — doubling is sufficient; it ensures that `grep` sees the backslash (this isn't a `system()` call where there's a shell to confuse things, and I don't want `grep` looking for an actual backslash).  Thanks!